# Sending objects through Java NIO non-blocking sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, nio

I am getting an exception when trying to use:

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketChannel.socket().getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(o);
```

And this raises the exception:

```
java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
```

Is it impossible to pass objects in non-blocking sockets?
If it is, how should I proceed on passing message objects through the socket channels?

I've looked other places for this answer but couldn't find one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to write your own `ObjectOutputStream` implementation that constructs a `ByteBuffer` and `write()`s it to the channel.

With non-blocking sockets, you cannot directly use the channel's socket; you need to use the channel's `read()` and `write()` methods.

When you write your own `ObjectOutputStream`, you'll mainly need to override the `write()` methods to buffer output and use the `flush()` method to write the buffer to the channel. Then, override the `writeObject()` method to look like this:

```
public void writeObject(Object o) throws IOException {
    super.writeObject(o);
    flush();
}
```

to make sure the data gets written after each object write.

Comment: So basically, I'd make my own output stream and simply change it to write with ByteBuffer instead of byte[] but I don't understand how I'm going to use this output stream if I cannot get the socket's stream. Sorry but I never used this kind of lower level communication in java. An example would be awesome.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant that this new output stream would wrap the channel, using the channel's `write()` method, rather than the channel's socket's `write()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked in this area but it seemed to be more complex than simply wrapping `writeObject`.  `java.nio` typically expects fixed size buffers (though you can dynamically allocate them I believe) and your remote endpoints need to know how much to read for an arbitrary `Object` coming down the wire.  What I ended up doing was to send an initial `int` header telling the other end how much data to expect, and then serializing the object to a byte array and sending that down the wire.

I've [got an example of this](http://virtualcommons.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/virtualcommons/csidex/trunk/src/main/java/edu/asu/commons/net/NioDispatcher.java?revision=533&view=markup) that may still have some bugs, so use at your own risk.  The `PendingDataBufferS` are needed to deal with objects that are larger than the initially allocated fixed size buffer.